# Formatting a date - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a variable containing a date in this form: (2018-03-21 18:49:49 UTC)
and I would like to display in this form: (day / month / year) but I can not find a solution. Do you have an idea ? Thank you !

Comment: You might find [this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+format+date) helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I guess this could work.

print "What year?"
year = gets.chomp!

print "What number month?"
month = gets.chomp!

print "What number day?"
day = gets.chomp!

puts "#{day}/#{month}/#{year}"

I'm new to ruby but I think this should work.

Comment: I guess isn't what he's asking. He just wants that somebody formats his date.

Comment: Oh. Okie I don't know what that is.I mean format.

Comment: Yes, formatting maybe with something like [this](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime).